# Using rxjs sample within redux-observable to listen to other actions

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using redux-observable to act as the middleware between dispatching actions and the store. I'm trying to use the rxjs `sample` function to accomplish this, but unfortunately it's not working for me. Here's my epic:

```
export const inviteUserEpic = (action$) => {
    return action$.ofType(a.INVITE_USER)
    .flatMap(({ body }) => {
        return Observable.concat(
            Observable.of({ type: authActions.REGISTER_REQ, body }),
            Observable.of(push(`/team/${body.teamId}`))
            .sample(action$.ofType(authActions.REGISTER_SUCCESS))
        );
    });
};
```

Basically the idea is that there are multiple places to register a new user, and in this case I want to redirect to the team page after I successfully register the user. I'm seeing REGISTER_REQ emit, and it will subsequently emit REGISTER_SUCCESS. But the redirect observable is never sampled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `sample` operator is only active and subscribing to the notifier when the source itself is still active. In this case, the source is an `Observable.of()` that will emit the provided action and then immediately `complete()`, meaning you will no longer be sampling anything--it's already `complete()` before your `REGISTER_SUCCESS` action is dispatched. i.e. `.sample()` does not prevent an observable chain from completing.

Instead, you'll want to start by matching the expected action, and then when matched map that to your `push()`. You probably also want to only listen for `REQUEST_SUCESS` once, not indefinitely, so you'll need to add a `.take(1)`

```js
action$.ofType(authActions.REGISTER_SUCCESS)
  .take(1)
  .map(() => push(`/team/${body.teamId}`))
```

Putting that together with your existing Epic

```js
export const inviteUserEpic = (action$) => {
    return action$.ofType(a.INVITE_USER)
    .flatMap(({ body }) => {
        return Observable.concat(
            Observable.of({ type: authActions.REGISTER_REQ, body }),
            action$.ofType(authActions.REGISTER_SUCCESS)
              .take(1)
              .map(() => push(`/team/${body.teamId}`))
        );
    });
};
```

You can see a working example of this here: http://jsbin.com/sonuqob/edit?js,output

Comment: @Jake Dluhy I forgot to mention that you probably don't want to listen for `REGISTER_SUCCESS` forever, in which case you should add a `.take(1)` so it completes after the first match. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing I thought of is wanting to cancel the redirect if the request fails. I added `.takeUntil(action$.ofType(authActions.REGISTER_FAILURE))` which seems to work.

Comment: Yep, that's perfect.